# Offsets to create n-sided shape around starting point in Javascript

Tags: javascript, math

I would like to find an function where, given a starting point (x, y) P, a radius r, and an integer n, I can generate offsets from P to create n well-placed points to create a shape (within a circle of radius r) around P.

For example:

```js
For P = {x: 0, y: 0}, r = 25.
Where "offsets" is the return value of the desired function...
Let n = 0:
    offsets = [];
Let n = 1:
    // Note 25 here is simply P.x + r, where P.x = 0 for simplicity's sake.
    // So x: 25 is actually x: P.x + 25
    // And y: 0 is actually y: P.y + 0
    // I've kept the simplified notation here and below for readability.
    offsets = [{x: 25, y: 0}];
Let n = 2: // Line
    offsets = [{x: 25, y: 0}, {x: -25, y: 0}];
Let n = 3: // Triangle
    offsets = [{x: 25, y: 0}, {x: -25, y: 0}, {x: 0, y: 25}];
Let n = 4: // Square
    offsets = [
      {x: 25, y: 0},
      {x: -25, y: 0},
      {x: 0, y: 25},
      {x: 0, y: -25}
    ];
Let n = 5: // Pentagon
    offsets = [
      {x: 25, y: 0},
      {x: -25, y: 0},
      {x: 0, y: 25},
      {x: -12.5, y: -25},
      {x: 12.5, y: -25}
    ];
```

.... and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just sample a circle:

```
allocate offset array
var angle = 2 * Math.PI / n;
for(var i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    offsets[i] = {x: r * Math.cos(i * angle), y: r * Math.sin(i * angle)};
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thanks!